# Approximate summation of flooring function

Tags: summation, approximation, ceiling-and-floor-functions

I have this summation:

$\sum_{k=0}^x \lfloor{\frac{k}{c}}\rfloor$

Do you have any ideas on any general expressions that can approximate this?

P.S I know I can approximate it with a Fourier expansion using $\{\frac{k}{c}\} = \frac{k}{c} \mod 1$, which is a sawtooth function, if I reform it to
$\lfloor{\frac{k}{c}\rfloor}=\frac{k}{c}-\{\frac{k}{c}\}$. However, I'm looking for something more general, easier to handle and computationally more tractable.

$c$ is an integer btw which I will need to iterate over in another step of my algorithm.

Thank you.

Comment: Why not just use the exact value of $\sum_k \lfloor k/c \rfloor$?  What's the context for needing to approximate it?

Comment: I needed a general expression in order to not calculate this algorithmically, as I need to plug it in another complex and slow algorithm. The problem is that for large integers calculating this is slow. Thank you for your suggestion, however.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With $c$ integer, an exact solution is easy.

From $k=0$ to $k=c-1$, the terms are $0$.

From $k=c$ to $k=2c-1$, the terms are $1$.

From $k=2c$ to $k=3c-1$, the terms are $2$.

...

Let $q=\lfloor\dfrac xc\rfloor$. You have full "periods" ($c$ equal terms) from $k=0$ to $cq-1$, then an incomplete period from  $cq$ to $x$ inclusive.

The total is

$$c\cdot0+c\cdot1+c\cdot2\cdots c\cdot(q-1)+(x-cq+1)q=c\frac{(q-1)q}2+(x-cq+1)q.$$

Comment: Crossed with @abiessu.

Comment: I see your point, thank you very much Yves. This seems simple enough and I'm surprised I didn't see it. Seems I've burned my brain these days. Thank you again, you have been most helpful.

Comment: @Sioux: thanks. The problem is more challenging when you allow rational or irrational $c$, as the periods can become unequal...

Answer (score 1):

With a given fixed value $c$, we have

$$\sum_{k=0}^x\left\lfloor\frac kc\right\rfloor=\sum_{k=c}^x\left\lfloor\frac kc\right\rfloor$$

and we can take this as a cue to the full result.  In particular, let $q=\lfloor\frac xc\rfloor$, then we have result

$$\sum_{k=0}^x\left\lfloor\frac kc\right\rfloor= c\binom q2+q(x+1-qc)$$

Plugging in e.g. $x=c-1,c,c+1$ shows the correct outcomes.

**EDIT**:

Considering that there is interest in computational complexity, it is worthwhile to consider how the result can be manipulated to create a quantity that has the fewest possible computations, or how it can be adjusted to reduce the computation expense.  In that vein, note that

$$c\binom q2-cq^2=c\frac{q^2-q}2-c\frac{2q^2}2=-c{q(q+1)\over 2}=-c\binom{q+1}2$$

so our modified result can be computed as

$$\sum_{k=0}^x\left\lfloor\frac kc\right\rfloor=q(x+1)-\frac{cq(q+1)}2$$

I have left the sum pieces undistributed (e.g., $q(x+1)$), but as the sums only involve increment by $1$, the "add first then multiply" efficiency is essentially non-existent.

Comment: You should "test" for values between the multiples of $c$ as well.

Comment: @YvesDaoust: agreed, I was going to put in $x=c-1,c,2c-1,2c,\dots$ but I thought that looked a little too long

Comment: To detect off-by-one errors, testing for $c-1,c-c+1$ would have been enough.

Comment: Thank you very much guys. I see your point, but in my case the solution below works better, because I need to plug this into another combinatorial problem and I don't want it to become too heavy.

Comment: @sioux: you're welcome; note that computationally, the two answers are identical as the results are identical with a notation difference.

Comment: @sioux: I have updated my answer as there is one significant computational efficiency point that is useful; in particular, two of the terms can be combined such that the overall computation can be reduced by at least one significant operation.